# Semi-Prime Number Originator Lookup For Identifying Prime Numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, inverse-function

In one of BBC's documentaries on security, a mathematician stated that prime and semi prime numbers helped with the design of RSA encryption - a number like 91 can be easily calculated through multiplication with two prime numbers 7 and 13, but its opposite operation (division) takes more effort, especially as we have larger and larger semi-prime numbers made up from prime numbers.

For reducing the complexity of calculating the opposite operation (division), what stops attackers from using a mathematical approach of using a lookup system of all semi prime numbers and their origins?  In other words, rather than trying to find the two prime numbers that make a semi prime number through multiplication, have a lookup of every semi prime number and the prime numbers that made it up?

This changes the mathematical complexity from a problem of trying to find the prime numbers that create a semi-prime number to finding the semi-prime equal value in a list and then getting the prime numbers.

Comment: Just that it would be an awfully big list.

Comment: Maybe a slight change, here, but building off your idea: use order-of-magnitude to constrain your lookup. If a prime is order $10^{50},$ then if you multiply a number of order $10^{25}$ by another of order $10^{25},$ you have a result of the right order. So you could search with one number starting at half the semi-prime, the other number at $2,$ and let the two approach each other in an intelligent way so that their orders of magnitude match the target.

Comment: It is utterly hopeless to list all the semiprimes being the product of two , lets say , $100$-digit primes. There are just too many. Nor is it possible to divide by all $100$-digit primes or to create all semiprimes of this form one by one in a reasonable time. Brute force will soon become infeasible.in practice.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes (and Peter too).  That is one major drawback, but it seems faster than trying to derive it by multiplying two prime numbers and testing if the output is the semi-prime.

Comment: It is better to come up with an algorithm for factorisation than creating a list, because as semi-primes grow in size, you would have to consider two factors: cost and time.

Comment: @KriyanshAurik Trial division is better than creating the semiprimes, but still far too slow. Modern integer factorization methods , like the elliptic curve method or the number field sieve , are far,far faster. Even the best computers could not factor a $100$-digit number in general in a reasonable time without the efficient methods known today.

Comment: And just guessing the factors would require too much luck. There is no hope to guess a $50$-digit prime factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are approximately $3.9 \times 10^{97}$ primes of $100$ digits, and   approximately $7.6 \times 10^{194}$ semiprimes formed from those primes.
The visible universe only has something like $10^{80}$ protons (the Eddington number), so a supercomputer composed of all the matter in the visible universe wouldn't come anywhere near being able to store all of these primes, let alone all the semiprimes.

Comment: Great answer and it wouldn't be possible. I feel it would be faster than deriving those values try-by-try, but there would need to be enough storage capacity, so not gonna happen.